# set grid x but not at 00:00:00.000

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to know if it possible to set grid x but that it does not start at time 00:00:00.000

```
set grid x layerdefault front
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M:%.3S"
set xrange ["00:00:00.000":maxtime]
```

[image]

Comment: Which gnuplot version and which terminal are you using?

Comment: `Version 5.2 patchlevel 8` & `terminal png`

Comment: so far, I cannot reproduce this with Win10, `terminal png`. You meant `png` not `pngcairo`? What is your operating system and your terminal size? Is there any other potentially relevant code which you don't show above?

Comment: I think I didn’t specify something that might be important (maybe but i'm not sure…) `set offsets 0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2` if `set offsets <left>` is equal at `0` it's ok but i would like specify a offset

Comment: well, that's it! If you specify `set offsets 0.1, ...` then the left offset is not `0` and that's why the grid is not identical with the y-axis and that's why it is visible. Right away, I don't know whether you can skip a specific grid line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid can be set to use any or all x tics (the labeled ones), mxtics ("minor", unlabeled ones), x2tics (secondary axis at the top) or mx2tics( minor tics on secondary axis.  For a plot such as the one you show, one option is to turn off the xtics and set up tics along x2 that omit the tic at zero.

```
... everything as before, then add ...
set x2data time      # configure secondary axis to match primary axis
set link x2          # same range and scale on both primary and secondary x axis
set grid nox x2      # set xtics off, x2tics on
set x2tics 30., 30.  # tics every 30 seconds starting at 30 seconds
set x2tics format "" # don't label the x2 tics
set x2tics scale 0,0 # we don't want the tic marks themselves, just the locations
```